# How to store 1 Key with 4 values dynamically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tuples

I want to save a default amount of dataset (1 unique Key `[timestamp as int]`, and 4 different sensor values) when starting the app. From that moment on new datasets, every 10 seconds, will be saved in the database. These datasets shall be added to the storage, e.g. a list of tuples. At the end I am plotting graphs by using the stored data.

The different values, which need to be stored, are the following:

- Timestamp: `int`
- Humidity sensor: `float`
- temp. sensor: `float`
- light sensor: `int`
- button "sensor": `boolean`

Unfortunately it seems that Unity Mono does not support Tuples with 4 values. So therefore this code is not working:

```
List<Tuple<int, float, float, int, boolean>> list = new List<Tuple<int, float, float, int, boolean>>();
```

It always pops up the message that the type `Tuple` requires 2 type arguments. `Dictionary`'s pro is the key value (my timestamp) but on the other side I was also only able to store two values (including the key).

A `List` of Tuples would be perfect, because if the user selects "display last 10 values" we add a new dataset, and remove the oldest one.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just create a flat model eg. `SensorValues` and store this in some kind of `Dictionary<int, SensorValues>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't work like that with a `Tuple` of 4-5 values.. It's difficult to track what each `Item` means and leads to bugs. Create a custom class:

```
public class SensorData
{
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public float Humidity { get; set; }
    public int Temp { get; set; }
    public int Light { get; set; }
    public bool Button { get; set; }
}
```

Then if you want a list/dictionary:

```
List<SensorData> list = new List<SensorData>();
Dictionary<int, SensorData> mapping = new Dictionary<int, SensorData>();
```

Then if the data you have is originally in a list you can use `.ToDictionary` to create the dictionary:

```
list.ToDictionary(key => key.TimeStamp); 
// Note that this will faild if you have sevetal items with the same timestamp
// If not unique then look at `.GroupBy` or `LookUp`
```

Comment: what is that `int` in `Dictionary<int, SensorData>` if the timestamp is already part of your `SensorData` class?

Comment: @fubo - that depends on how OP obtains the data. If it comes from some place where each record has it then it might be part of the object - that is already depending on the specific case. But both with and without that property dictionary option holds - depends on use

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. How would I then address e.g. to all Light values, to use for creating a graph?

Comment: @Cruzad0r - once you access the dictionary at some index, or iterate the list, the object you get back is instead of the Tuple the SensorData - access its properties: `item.Temp` (just like if it was a tuple but with better names than `Item1`)

Comment: Worked out really well so far, just my last step doesn't seem to work:
Debug.Log (list[i]);  doesn't show me all the list values on position i. What am I doing wrong here again?

Comment: that is because you need to override the `ToString`. See example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43806525/6400526)

Comment: immediate and an on spot solution again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `Dictionary` with a custom class which stores the Sensor results and the unique timestamp

```
public class SensorResult
{
    public float Humidity { get; set; }
    public float Temp { get; set; }
    public int Light { get; set; }
    public bool Button { get; set; }
}


Dictionary<int, SensorResult> items = new Dictionary<int, SensorResult>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to hold key and values and create a list of that class as follows -

```
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Declare your serializable data
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Data {
        public int a;
        public float b;
        public float c;
        public int d;
        public bool e;
    }

    // Create list of your class type
    public List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to keep those related set of values together, can't you?

```
public class SensorData {
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public float HumiditySensor { get; set; }
    public float TempSensor { get; set; }
    public int LightSensor { get; set; }
    public boolean ButtonSensor { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use a Dictionary to store your SensorData as key-value pairs:

```
/* ... */
var sensors = new Dictionary<int, SensorData>();

public void AddSensorData(SensorData data) {
    sensors.Add(data.Timestamp, data);
}
```